# Is it good practice to return true when success otherwise raise exception in python?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

Let’s say I have this function :

```
def a ():

   try :
     b
   except Error:
     raise Error
   return True
```

Is this considered good practice to only return true if it is successful otherwise stop block execution with raise error ?

Comment: Why are you catching the error to raise the same error?

Comment: Nope, return a value instead of a boolean value (for further operation)

Comment: No, usually a function returns nothing (actually "None") or a requested result on success and raise on error and some return True or False on success/fail respectively. Some also return requested data on success and None on error.

Comment: I am raising an error because I want the function to stop executing.

Answer (score 1):

Think about your function and error processing as separate concerns. A function should either return an object as the result (or automatically `None` with no `return` statement) or perform some action without returning an explicit result. Avoid mixing the two.

If an error that your function code can detect happens, rise an `Exception` at the appropriate abstraction level, so that the client code can wrap the call in a `try` block and properly treat the error case, if there is a wish to do so.